# Add hops on a single machine and forward some trafic to another

Tags: ubuntu, networking, ip, route

I want to change this script [simulating-network-hops-on-a-single-linux-box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34320429/simulating-network-hops-on-a-single-linux-box)

So it will forward only some traffic to another machine.

Assuming that my address is 192.168.0.3 and I want to add hops and forward it to 192.168.0.4. How can I do it?
I tried to edit the last line:

route add -net 172.16.101.0/24 gw 172.16.100.2

but lost connectivity :(